# Custom Visual Web Part editable CSS

Tags: visual-studio, css, visual-web-part, cssregistration

I am making a custom visual web part in Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to add a editable CSS style sheet to it. What I mean is I want to make a property that the user can access through the edit web part menu. This property will be a text field that contains the CSS style sheet. The goal is to have the CSS Classes within the web part be adjustable at any time with out having to recompile and publish the web part.

has this been done? Can this be done? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually really simple. I just need to add a string property and then add that string to the style tag inside the page header.

Answer (score 1):

Why not deploy your CSS file to the Style Library. In this way you can update your CSS by uploading newer version of your css file directly to style library.

Comment: The people who will be using it will not want to have to go through that many steps, the changes that will be made are simple changes such as color change or something and the goal is to make it quick and easy for  slightly technical users to open up the style sheet under edit web part  and change small items. I personally agree that a version-ed approach is better but these are my requirements.